Testing component that is using axios and tanstack query
So I have a component that is using hook to get data from server. If data was fetched successfully component displays the list of item, if there was some errors component displays error message and while loading it displays loading spinner. That are exactly three components states that I want to test.
My hook to get data is using useQuery from @tanstack/react-query and axios.
import axiosInstance from './axiosConfig';
import {useQuery, keepPreviousData} from '@tanstack/react-query';
import useUserStore from '../reactiveVariablesStore/userStore';
import {MediaSort, MediaStatus} from '../API/__generated__/graphql';

type GetAnimeQueryParams = {
  page: number;
  sortType?: MediaSort;
  name?: string;
  genre?: string;
  startDateGreater?: string;
  status?: MediaStatus;
  startDateLesser?: string;
};

const QUERY_KEY = ['GetAnime'];

const getAnime = async (params: GetAnimeQueryParams) => {
  const userTokenId = useUserStore.getState().userTokenId;
  try {
    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = userTokenId;
    const {data} = await axiosInstance.get('/anilist/animes', {params});
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('GET_ANIME_ERROR', error);
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  }
};

export const useGetAnime = (params: GetAnimeQueryParams) => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [...QUERY_KEY, params],
    queryFn: () => getAnime(params),
    placeholderData: keepPreviousData,
  });
};

I'm trying to mock the response, to do it i'm using jest-mock-axios lib. My tests looks like this
import React from 'react';
import {render, waitFor, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import {MediaSort} from '../src/API/__generated__/graphql.ts';
import {Anime} from '../src/screens/anime.tsx';
import {it, expect, jest, afterEach, describe} from '@jest/globals';
import {MockedNavigator} from './__mocks__/mocks.tsx';
// import {currentScreen} from '../src/reactiveVariablesStore/currentScreen.ts';
import {GraphQLError} from 'graphql/error';
import useCurrentScreenStore from '../src/reactiveVariablesStore/currentScreenStore.ts';
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import axiosInstance from '../src/API/axiosConfig.ts';
import {QueryCache} from '@tanstack/react-query';
import mockAxios from 'jest-mock-axios';

jest.useFakeTimers();

const queryCache = new QueryCache();

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  queryCache.clear();
  cleanup();
  mockAxios.reset();
});

const mocks = [...some mock];

const mockResponse = (type: any) => {
  if (type === 'success') {
    mockAxios.mockResponse({data: mocks[0].result.data, status: 200});
  }
  if (type === 'error') {
    mockAxios.mockError();
  }
};

describe('Success', () => {
  it('renders without error', async () => {
    useCurrentScreenStore.getState().setCurrentScreen('Anime');
    const wrapper = render(<MockedNavigator component={Anime} mocks={mocks} />);
    mockResponse('success');
    await waitFor(() => [
      expect(wrapper.queryAllByText('Some title')).toHaveLength(1),
      expect(wrapper.queryByTestId('item-card')).toBeTruthy(),
      expect(wrapper.getAllByTestId('item-card')).toHaveLength(1),
    ]);
  });
});

describe('Error', () => {
  it('should error message there was an error on loading data', async () => {
    useCurrentScreenStore.getState().setCurrentScreen('Anime');
    const wrapper = render(<MockedNavigator component={Anime} />);
    mockResponse('error');
    await waitFor(() => [
      expect(wrapper.getAllByText('Failed to load data')).toHaveLength(1),
    ]);
  });
});

I also had test for loading state but removed it due to an issue I have while testing.
So the issue is that error test never works together with success test. Only first test works properly, in provided implementation it is success test, if I change tests order, then it will be error test. If I comment success test then error test will work fine, but if I will run test as is in code example then data from mocked response will be set every time I run tests, even if it is error test that should set error. I'm not sure will it overwright error or error just never occurs. I'm not sure about my conclusion but I think that mockAxios.mockResponse runs with every test, but I just can't figure out why does it happens.
Do you have any ideas?

You generally need to mock something, before it happens. I mean mockResponse('success'); should probably be before the render(<MockedNavigator component={Anime} mocks={mocks} />);. Another observation is that waitFor and useFakerTimers, I believe does not work very well together https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/631
